# How to get the nth element of a python list or a default if not available

Tags: python, list

In Python, how can I simply do the equivalent of `dictionary.get(key, default)` for lists - i.e., how can I simply get the nth element of a list, or a default value if not available?

For example, given a list `myList`, how can I get `5` if `myList` is empty, or `myList[0]` otherwise?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

```
l[index] if index < len(l) else default
```

To support negative indices we can use:

```
l[index] if -len(l) <= index < len(l) else default
```

Comment: this looks to me like the clearest syntax, and it does work for empty list, thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work if your list doesn't have a name, though - for instance, in a list comprehension.

Comment: You seem to forgot the case of negative index.  Eg. `index == -1000000` should return `default`.

Comment: @nodakai, good point. I've sometimes been bitten by this. `x[index] if 0 <= index < len(x) else default` would be better if `index` can ever be negative.

Comment: @nodakai wow - that is a great example of why it may be better to use try/except, than to try to correctly code the test so it never fails. I still don't like to rely on try/except, for a case that I know will happen, but this increases my willingness to consider it.

Comment: @XiongChiamiov I would assume that ANY of these solutions would be made into a def, to be used instead of `L[index]`. E.g. `def safeget(L, index, default):` `return L[index] if index < len(L) else default`. Can you give a code sample where it would be possible to do `..[index]`, but not possible to replace that with `safeget(.., index, default)`?

Comment: BTW, testing for valid index is useful enough, that it is worth defining `def validIndex(lst, index): return 0 <= index < len(lst)` in a common.py or whatever, then `from common import *`, and then the code becomes the readable and reliable `x[index] if validIndex(lst, index) else default`

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Assuming this will be made into a def is assuming quite a lot; most of my Python is 100-line scripts that don't have *any* functions in them.  And since the OP asked specifically for a one-liner, it seems a fair assumption he also wasn't going to wrap these solutions in a function.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve: Your formula for `valid_index()` is incorrect. Negative indices *are* legal in Python - it should be `-len(l) <= index < len(l)`.

Comment: Note that this does might check the length twice - once in your code and once in the index operator.

Comment: Hey Manu, what kind of context would you be looking for? I'm happy to amend the answer, if you could give me some more details about what you are looking for.

Comment: @XiongChiamiov It does in Python 3.8, though I'm not a fan of mangling the syntax quite as hard as this `ls[index] if index < len(ls:=[x*2 for x in iterator]) else default` or `ls[index] * 2 if index < len(ls:=list(iterator)) else default`, plus as ToolmakerSteve says, it works in a def too

Answer (score 75):

```
try:
   a = b[n]
except IndexError:
   a = default
```

Edit: I removed the check for TypeError - probably better to let the caller handle this.

Comment: I like this. Just wrap it around a function so that you can call it with an iterable as an argument. Easier to read.

Answer (score 52):

```
(a[n:]+[default])[0]
```

This is probably better as `a` gets larger

```
(a[n:n+1]+[default])[0]
```

This works because if `a[n:]` is an empty list if `n => len(a)`

Here is an example of how this works with `range(5)`

```
>>> range(5)[3:4]
[3]
>>> range(5)[4:5]
[4]
>>> range(5)[5:6]
[]
>>> range(5)[6:7]
[]
```

And the full expression

```
>>> (range(5)[3:4]+[999])[0]
3
>>> (range(5)[4:5]+[999])[0]
4
>>> (range(5)[5:6]+[999])[0]
999
>>> (range(5)[6:7]+[999])[0]
999
```

Comment: Would you write this in actual code without a comment to explain it?

Comment: @Peter Hansen, only if I was golfing ;) However it does work on _all_ versions of Python. The Accepted answer only works on 2.5+

Comment: It invloves creating 3 temporary lists and accessing 2 indices in order to select an item, though.

Comment: While I'd never do this in "real" code, it's a nice concise one-liner that I can easily use in a python REPL, so you get my upvote.

Comment: `next(iter(lst[i:i+1]), default)` -- just another entry in the cryptic ugly one-liners competition.

Comment: And even shorter: `next(iter(lst[i:]), default)`

Answer (score 51):

Just discovered that :

```
next(iter(myList), 5)
```

`iter(l)` returns an iterator on `myList`, `next()` consumes the first element of the iterator, and raises a `StopIteration` error except if called with a default value, which is the case here, the second argument, `5`

This only works when you want the 1st element, which is the case in your example, but not in the text of you question, so...

Additionally, it does not need to create temporary lists in memory and it works for any kind of iterable, even if it does not have a name (see Xiong Chiamiov's comment on gruszczy's answer)

Comment: Combined with the other answers:  `next(iter(myList[n:n+1]), 5)`  Now it works for the `n`th element.

Comment: That would not work with non lists. At this point, try:except-ing an IndexError reads like a better idea IMHO. Also, it creates a list in memory.

Comment: The `try` variant isn't a one-liner (ask asked for by OP).  It only works for lists because `myList` is a list as specified by OP (to be precise, it is something indexable).  Creating a copy in memory isn't costly here because I'm creating a list of one single (or none) element here.  Sure, a little overhead, but not worth mentioning unless you do that millions of times in a loop.  Btw, I guess creating and catching an `IndexError` exception is probably more costly.

Comment: readability counts :) If you're at the point where raising an IndexError has a significant cost, maybe you should be doing the whole thing in Python.

Answer (score 32):

```
(L[n:n+1] or [somedefault])[0]
```

Comment: +1 because this made me go learn what `[] or ...` did. However, I would personally just use the accepted solution, as it reads easily (for novices). Granted, wrapping it in a 'def' with comment would make that largely a non-issue.

Comment: What if `L[n] == False` or `L[n] == None` or `L[n] == []` or more globally anything that evaluates to False ?

Comment: @JoachimJablon: Still works. The slice returns a list, and `[False]` is true.

Comment: Oh, didn't realised the list was checked and not the value, indeed.

Comment: Why do you wrap this in a tuple? I think `myval = l[n:n+1] or [somedefault]` would work just fine?

Comment: @Rotareti: `myval` is a list (one item) in your case. To get scalar, you need to unpack it: `[value] = lst[i:i+1] or [default]`. It is still ugly.

Comment: @jfs Ah, makes sense. It's indeed ugly.. I think it sucks that the proposal for `mylist.get(myindex, default)` was rejected... Would be good too have the `get()` function for lists as well. IMHO

Answer (score 16):

> ... looking for an equivalent in python of `dict.get(key, default)` for lists

There is an [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) that does this for general iterables.  For convenience, you can [`> pip install more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) and import this third-party library that implements such recipes for you:

**Code**

```
import more_itertools as mit


mit.nth([1, 2, 3], 0)
# 1    

mit.nth([], 0, 5)
# 5
```

---

**Detail**

Here is the implementation of the `nth` recipe:

```
def nth(iterable, n, default=None):
    "Returns the nth item or a default value"
    return next(itertools.islice(iterable, n, None), default)
```

Like `dict.get()`, this tool returns a default for missing indices.  It applies to  general iterables:

```
mit.nth((0, 1, 2), 1)                                      # tuple
# 1

mit.nth(range(3), 1)                                       # range generator (py3)
# 1

mit.nth(iter([0, 1, 2]), 1)                                # list iterator 
# 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Using Python 3.4's `contextlib.suppress(exceptions)` to build a `getitem()` method similar to `getattr()`.

```
import contextlib

def getitem(iterable, index, default=None):
    """Return iterable[index] or default if IndexError is raised."""
    with contextlib.suppress(IndexError):
        return iterable[index]
    return default
```

Answer (score 3):

A cheap solution is to really make a dict with enumerate and use `.get()` as usual, like

```
 dict(enumerate(l)).get(7, my_default)
```

Comment: This is very slow to run because whole list is converted to a dictionary only to get later just one element.

Answer (score 3):

With unpacking:

```py
b, = a[n:n+1] or [default]
```

Answer (score 2):

Combining @Joachim's with the above, you could use

```
next(iter(my_list[index:index+1]), default)
```

Examples:

```
next(iter(range(10)[8:9]), 11)
8
>>> next(iter(range(10)[12:13]), 11)
11
```

---

Or, maybe more clear, but without the `len`

```
my_list[index] if my_list[index:index + 1] else default
```

Comment: if my_list is a very large list, this could behave badly.
Maybe next(iter(my_list[index:index + 1]), default)

Answer (score 2):

After reading through the answers, I'm going to use:

```py
(L[n:] or [somedefault])[0]
```

Comment: Probably you want `(L[n:n+1] or [somedefault])[0]` (n+1 added) instead, because `L[n:]` creates long list and copies all elements from `n` to the end. Only to get just one element afterwards. While `L[n:n+1]` creates a list of just 1 element at most.

Comment: I believe I chose the form I give because I need to compute `n`, and I do not want to compute it twice, nor introduce a variable. My lists are short. -- Also, the answer `L[n:n+1]` has already been provided by Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams

Comment: I don't get it. If you need to compute `n`, you will have it in the context, there's no need to compute it twice. Why not sum one and prevent the rest of the list from being copied?

Answer (score 2):

Althought this is not a one-liner solution, you can define a function with a default value like so:

```py
def get_val(myList, idx, default=5):
    try:
        return myList[idx]
    except IndexError:
        return default
```

Comment: Thanks @VictorSchröder. Edited the answer!

Comment: I removed my previous comment, as the issue was fixed. The solution still has limitations in case `myList` is not of `List` type or if `idx` is not an `int`, but that's out of the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

For a small index, such as when parsing up to `k` arguments, I'd build a new list of length `k`, with added elements set to `d`, as follows:

```py
def fill(l, k, d): 
    return l + (k - len(l)) * [d]
```

Typical usage:

```py
N = 2
arg_one, arg_two = fill("first_word and the rest".split(maxsplit=N - 1), N, None)
# arg_one == "first_word"
# arg_two == "and the rest"
```

Same example, with a short list:

```py
arg_one, arg_two = fill("one_word_only".split(maxsplit=N - 1), N, None)
# arg_one == "one_word_only"
# arg_two == None
```

Answer (score 0):

I like it more inline, therefore I created a little streams-like library (https://pypi.org/project/tinystream/).

```py
my_list = ["a", "b", "c"]

stream = Stream(my_list)
assert stream[4].absent
assert stream[0].get() == "a"
```

Since the index element is of type `Opt`, you can also do more stuff like:

```
assert stream[4].get('X') == 'X'  # default if absent
assert stream[0].map(str.upper).filter(lambda x: x == 'A').present
```