# evaluating a complex conditional python

Tags: python, conditional-statements

```
show_prev_btn = (len(sessions) > 0 and (sessions[0].pk == \
    Session.objects.filter(user=request.user).first().pk))
```

I have this boolean that I'm calculating. Sessions is a list and if it has 0 elements, sessions[0] will raise an exception. Fortunately, I think that I can catch it before it's evaluated by checking len(sessions) > 0.

This works on my local development machine, but is this okay practice or should I nest these conditionals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python, the `and` operator is [defined to use *short-circuit evaluation*](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations). So if you have an expression like

```
a() and b()
```

then first `a()` will be called. Only if that returns `True`, will `b()` be called. If `a()` returns `False`, then `b()` will not be called, so you can do things in `b()` that might crash if `a()` is `False`.

This is certainly accepted practice and is widely used.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of nesting the conditions is that, in this specific case, it might improve readability a bit (by reducing line length).

Although in my opinion both are equally good solutions it's a matter of taste and code style more than anything else (doubt the performance differences, if any, would have a great impact).

Answer (score 0):

To copy from [an older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492087/how-to-get-the-nth-element-of-a-python-list-or-a-default-if-not-available), try this. The syntax is more intuitive, though the difference is arbitrary.

```
sessions[0].pk == Session.objects.filter(user=request.user).first().pk) if len(sessions) else False
```