# Find the first index in a list A where the value is in a list B

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I want to find the first index in `A` that contains a value from `B`. For example:

```
A = [1, 'Q', 3, 6, 'R']
B = ['Z', 'I', 'O', 3]
A.function(B)  # would return 2
```

Is there a simple way of doing this? Obviously you can search through `A` for each item in `B` and take the minimum index, but this is slower than trying all of `B` for each index.

Comment: It depends which list is longer, as to whether finding the index of each item and taking the minimum is faster than searching through `B` on item at a time and seeing if it's in `A`.

Comment: finding the index of each item is O(A*B) always. the second method is O(A*B) in the worst case and O(1) in the best case.

Answer (score 4):

I think there are two broad approaches, depending on which list is longer:

1. **`A` is longer than `B`**:

   Take one item in `A` at a time and see if it's in `B`. Repeat until you find the first one that is.

   ```
   next(index for index, item in enumerate(A) if item in B)
   ```

   This is more efficient if `B` is converted to a `set` (thanks [@khelwood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38220117/find-the-first-index-in-a-list-a-where-the-value-is-in-a-list-b/38220228?noredirect=1#comment63863127_38220228)), but be sure to do that *before* you start, not inside the generator expression.
2. **`B` is longer than `A`**:

   Find the index in `A` of every item in `B`, then minimise:

   ```
   indices = []
   for item in B:
       try:
           indices.append(A.index(item))
       except ValueError:
           pass
   min(indices)
   ```

   Note that you cannot use:

   ```
   min(index for index in map(A.index, B) if index > -1)
   ```

   (oops!) because `list` doesn't have a method to get an index without an error (see e.g. [list.index() function for Python that doesn't throw exception when nothing found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8197323/3001761)).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to iterate over every element of the first list, and check if each is in the second list.

```
def firstInBoth(A, B):
    for x in range(len(A)):
        if A[x] in B:
            return x
```