# Why dict.get(key) instead of dict[key]?

Tags: python, dictionary, lookup

I came across the `dict` method `get` which, given a key in the dictionary, returns the associated value.

For what purpose is this function useful? If I wanted to find a value associated with a key in a dictionary, I can just do `dict[key]`, and it returns the same thing:

```py
dictionary = {"Name": "Harry", "Age": 17}
dictionary["Name"] == dictionary.get("Name")      # True
```

---

<sub>**See also:** [Return a default value if a dictionary key is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6130768)</sub>

Answer (score 1611, accepted):

It allows you to provide a default value if the key is missing:

```
dictionary.get("bogus", default_value)
```

returns `default_value` (whatever you choose it to be), whereas

```
dictionary["bogus"]
```

would raise a `KeyError`.

If omitted, `default_value` is `None`, such that

```
dictionary.get("bogus")  # <-- No default specified -- defaults to None
```

returns `None` just like

```
dictionary.get("bogus", None)
```

would.

Comment: It's very useful in reinforcement learning that requires randomized initialization: e.g. `q_sa = q.get((s, action), random())`

Comment: Would this be the same as `dictionary.get("bogus") or my_default`? I've seen people use it in some cases and I was wondering if there's any advantage of using one instead of the other (other than readability)

Comment: @MustafaS: If `"bogus"` is a key in `dictionary` and `dictionary.get("bogus")` returns a value which evaluates to False in a boolean context (i.e. a Falsey value), such as 0 or an empty string, `''`, then `dictionary.get("bogus") or my_default` would evaluate to `my_default` whereas `dictionary.get("bogus", my_default)` would return the Falsey value. So no, `dictionary.get("bogus") or my_default` is not equivalent to `dictionary.get("bogus", my_default)`. Which to use depends on the behavior you desire.

Comment: @MustafaS: For example, suppose `x = {'a':0}`. Then `x.get('a', 'foo')` returns `0` but `x.get('a') or 'foo'` returns `'foo'`.

Comment: One possible caveat when using `dictionary.get('key')`: It can be confusing if values in the dictionary are `None`. Without specifying the return value (second optional argument) there is no way to verify if the key didn't exist or if its value is `None`. In this specific case I would consider using `try-except-KeyError`.

Comment: It's worth noting that the expression to specify the default value is evaluated in the "get" call, and is therefore evaluated on each access.

A classic alternative (using either a KeyError handler or a predicate) is to evaluate the default value only if the key is missing. This allows a closure/lambda to be created once and evaluated on any missing key.

Comment: @AartGoossens Or you could use `if 'key' in dictionary`, to avoid using `try-except` and to make the code easier to understand.

Comment: @AartGoossens: Agreed. But the primary purpose of `get()` is to conveniently get a value with defined semantics from the dict, regardless whether the key is in the dict or not. This is the very definition and the very purpose of a default value. Using a specific default value to check whether the key is present in a dict is always a hack.

Comment: Hasn't this been supplanted somewhat by defaultdict?   Unless, you want a different default for every missing value.

Answer (score 232):

> **What is the `dict.get()` method?**

As already mentioned the `get` method contains an additional parameter which indicates the missing value. [From the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

> ```
> get(key[, default])
> ```
>
> Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never raises a `KeyError`.

An example can be

```
>>> d = {1:2,2:3}
>>> d[1]
2
>>> d.get(1)
2
>>> d.get(3)
>>> repr(d.get(3))
'None'
>>> d.get(3,1)
1
```

> **Are there speed improvements anywhere?**

As mentioned [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips),

> It seems that all three approaches now exhibit similar performance (within about 10% of each other), more or less independent of the properties of the list of words.

Earlier `get` was considerably slower, However now the speed is almost comparable along with the additional advantage of returning the default value. But to clear all our queries, we can test on a fairly large list (Note that the test includes looking up all the valid keys only)

```
def getway(d):
    for i in range(100):
        s = d.get(i)

def lookup(d):
    for i in range(100):
        s = d[i]
```

Now timing these two functions using [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html)

```
>>> import timeit
>>> print(timeit.timeit("getway({i:i for i in range(100)})","from __main__ import getway"))
20.2124660015
>>> print(timeit.timeit("lookup({i:i for i in range(100)})","from __main__ import lookup"))
16.16223979
```

As we can see the lookup is faster than the get as there is no function lookup. This can be seen through [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html)

```
>>> def lookup(d,val):
...     return d[val]
... 
>>> def getway(d,val):
...     return d.get(val)
... 
>>> dis.dis(getway)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (d)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (get)
              6 LOAD_FAST                1 (val)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(lookup)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (d)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (val)
              6 BINARY_SUBSCR       
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

> **Where will it be useful?**

It will be useful whenever you want to provide a default value whenever you are looking up a dictionary. This reduces

```
 if key in dic:
      val = dic[key]
 else:
      val = def_val
```

To a single line, `val = dic.get(key,def_val)`

> **Where will it be NOT useful?**

Whenever you want to return a `KeyError` stating that the particular key is not available. Returning a default value also carries the risk that a particular default value may be a key too!

> **Is it possible to have `get` like feature in `dict['key']`?**

Yes! We need to implement the [`__missing__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__missing__) in a dict subclass.

A sample program can be

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return None
```

A small demonstration can be

```
>>> my_d = MyDict({1:2,2:3})
>>> my_d[1]
2
>>> my_d[3]
>>> repr(my_d[3])
'None'
```

Comment: [Playground link with these code](https://repl.it/Gz4w/latest)

Comment: One more good test would be `if k in dict and dict[k]:` vs `if dict.get(k):`. This covers the situation when we need to check if key exists, and if 'yes' - what value?, something like: `dict = {1: '', 2: 'some value'}`.

Comment: Please remember that default value gets evaluated regardless of the value being in dictionary, so instead of 
`dictionary.get(value, long_function())`
one might consider using
`dictionary.get(value) or long_function()`

Comment: @Kresimir The two methods are not the same, because `None` or a False-y value would default, while `dictionary.get()` would return the default value only if it is missing.

Comment: The `collections` module also has `defaultdict`, so no need to write a new class anymore.

Answer (score 38):

`get` takes a second optional value.  If the specified key does not exist in your dictionary, then this value will be returned.

```
dictionary = {"Name": "Harry", "Age": 17}
dictionary.get('Year', 'No available data')
>> 'No available data'
```

If you do not give the second parameter, `None` will be returned.

If you use indexing as in `dictionary['Year']`, nonexistent keys will raise `KeyError`.

Answer (score 31):

A gotcha to be aware of when using `.get()`:

If the dictionary contains the key used in the call to `.get()` and its value is `None`, the `.get()` method will return `None` even if a default value is supplied.

For example, the following returns `None`, not `'alt_value'` as may be expected:

```
d = {'key': None}
assert None is d.get('key', 'alt_value')
```

`.get()`'s second value is only returned if the key supplied is NOT in the dictionary, not if the return value of that call is `None`.

Comment: This one got me :\ One way to solve this is to have `d.get('key') or 'alt_value'` if you know it might be `None`

Comment: More like a getcha'

Answer (score 26):

I will give a practical example in scraping web data using python, a lot of the times you will get keys with no values, in those cases you will get errors if you use dictionary['key'], whereas dictionary.get('key', 'return_otherwise') has no problems.

Similarly, I would use ''.join(list) as opposed to list[0] if you try to capture a single value from a list.

hope it helps.

[Edit] Here is a practical example:

Say, you are calling an API, which returns a JOSN file you need to parse. The first JSON looks like following:

```
{"bids":{"id":16210506,"submitdate":"2011-10-16 15:53:25","submitdate_f":"10\/16\/2011 at 21:53 CEST","submitdate_f2":"p\u0159ed 2 lety","submitdate_ts":1318794805,"users_id":"2674360","project_id":"1250499"}}
```

The second JOSN is like this:

```
{"bids":{"id":16210506,"submitdate":"2011-10-16 15:53:25","submitdate_f":"10\/16\/2011 at 21:53 CEST","submitdate_f2":"p\u0159ed 2 lety","users_id":"2674360","project_id":"1250499"}}
```

Note that the second JSON is missing the "submitdate_ts" key, which is pretty normal in any data structure.

So when you try to access the value of that key in a loop, can you call it with the following:

```
for item in API_call:
    submitdate_ts = item["bids"]["submitdate_ts"]
```

You could, but it will give you a traceback error for the second JSON line, because the key simply doesn't exist.

The appropriate way of coding this, could be the following:

```
for item in API_call:
    submitdate_ts = item.get("bids", {'x': None}).get("submitdate_ts")
```

{'x': None} is there to avoid the second level getting an error. Of course you can build in more fault tolerance into the code if you are doing scraping. Like first specifying a if condition

Comment: A good answer, posted before any of the others, which would have been upvoted more, and probably accepted, if you had posted some code examples (+1 from me, though)

Comment: @Mawg I recently had a scraping project for my research. It was calling an API and parsing JSON files basically. I had my RA do it. One of the key issues he had was calling the key directly, when many keys are actually missing. I will post an example in the text above.

Comment: thanks for tackling the multi-dimensional aspect of this! Sounds like you can even just do {} instead of {'x': None}

Answer (score 21):

The purpose is that you can give a default value if the key is not found, which is very useful

```
dictionary.get("Name",'harry')
```

Answer (score 12):

> For what purpose is this function useful?

One particular usage is counting with a dictionary. Let's assume you want to count the number of occurrences of each element in a given list. The common way to do so is to make a dictionary where keys are elements and values are the number of occurrences.

```
fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'peach', 'apple', 'pear']
d = {}
for fruit in fruits:
    if fruit not in d:
        d[fruit] = 0
    d[fruit] += 1
```

Using the `.get()` method, you can make this code more compact and clear:

```
for fruit in fruits:
    d[fruit] = d.get(fruit, 0) + 1
```

Comment: While this is true, bear in mind that `d = defaultdict(int)` is even cleaner. Inner loop becomes `d[fruit] += 1`. Then again, probably `collections.Counter` is better still than the `defaultdict` version. The `.get` version may still be useful if you don't want to convert a `Counter` or `defaultdict` back to a `dict` or something like that.

Answer (score 12):

Other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37968524/6243352) have clearly explained the difference between dict bracket keying and `.get` and [mentioned a *fairly* innocuous pitfall](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57582439/6243352) when `None` or the default value is also a valid key.

Given this information, it may be tempting conclude that `.get` is somehow safer and better than bracket indexing and should always be used instead of bracket lookups, as argued in [*Stop Using Square Bracket Notation to Get a Dictionary's Value in Python*](https://medium.com/better-programming/stop-using-square-bracket-notation-to-get-a-dictionarys-value-in-python-c617f6ea15a3), even in the common case when they expect the lookup to succeed (i.e. never raise a `KeyError`).

The author of the blog post argues that `.get` "safeguards your code":

> Notice how trying to reference a term that doesn't exist causes a `KeyError`. This can cause major headaches, especially when dealing with unpredictable business data.
>
> While we could wrap our statement in a `try`/`except` or `if` statement, this much care for a dictionary term will quickly pile up.

It's true that in the uncommon case for [null](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare#Apologies_and_retractions) (`None`)-coalescing or otherwise filling in a missing value to handle unpredictable dynamic data, a judiciously-deployed `.get` is a useful and Pythonic shorthand tool for ungainly `if key in dct:` and `try`/`except` blocks that only exist to set default values when the key might be missing as part of the behavioral specification for the program.

However, replacing *all* bracket dict lookups, including those that you assert must succeed, with `.get` is a different matter. This practice effectively downgrades a class of [runtime errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runtime_error_detection) that help reveal bugs into silent illegal state scenarios that tend to be harder to identify and debug.

A common mistake among programmers is to think exceptions *cause* headaches and attempt to suppress them, using techniques like wrapping code in [`try` ... `except: pass` blocks](https://wiki.c2.com/?PokemonExceptionHandling). They later realize the *real* headache is never seeing the breach of application logic at the point of failure and deploying a broken application. Better programming practice is to embrace assertions for all program invariants such as keys that must be in a dictionary.

The hierarchy of error safety is, broadly:

| Error category | Relative ease of debugging |
| --- | --- |
| Compile-time error | Easy; go to the line and fix the problem |
| Runtime exception | Medium; control needs to flow to the error and it may be due to unanticipated edge cases or hard-to-reproduce state like a race condition between threads, but at least we get a clear error message and stack trace when it does happen. |
| Silent logical error | Difficult; we may not even know it exists, and when we do, tracking down state that caused it can be very challenging due to lack of locality and potential for multiple assertion breaches. |

When programming language designers talk about program safety, a major goal is to surface, not suppress, genuine errors by promoting runtime errors to compile-time errors and promote silent logical errors to either runtime exceptions or (ideally) compile-time errors.

Python, by design as an interpreted language, relies heavily on runtime exceptions instead of compiler errors. Missing methods or properties, illegal type operations like `1 + "a"` and out of bounds or missing indices or keys raise by default.

Some languages like JS, Java, Rust and Go use the fallback behavior for their maps by default (and in many cases, don't provide a throw/raise alternative), but Python throws by default, along with other languages like C#. Perl/PHP issue an uninitialized value warning.

Indiscriminate application of `.get` to all dict accesses, even those that aren't expected to fail and have no fallback for dealing with `None` (or whatever default is used) running amok through the code, pretty much tosses away Python's runtime exception safety net for this class of errors, silencing or adding indirection to potential bugs.

Other supporting reasons to prefer bracket lookups (with the occasional, well-placed `.get` where a default is expected):

- Prefer writing standard, idiomatic code using the tools provided by the language. Python programmers usually (correctly) prefer brackets for the exception safety reasons given above and because it's the default behavior for Python dicts.
- Always using `.get` forfeits intent by making cases when you expect to provide a default `None` value indistinguishable from a lookup you assert must succeed.
- Testing increases in complexity in proportion to the new "legal" program paths permitted by `.get`. Effectively, each lookup is now a branch that can succeed or fail -- both cases must be tested to establish coverage, even if the default path is effectively unreachable by specification (ironically leading to additional `if val is not None:` or `try` for all future uses of the retrieved value; unnecessary and confusing for something that should never be `None` in the first place).
- [`.get` is a bit slower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39582115/python-dictionary-lookup-performance-get-vs-in).
- `.get` is harder to type and uglier to read (compare Java's tacked-on-feel `ArrayList` syntax to native-feel C# `Lists` or C++ vector code). Minor.

Some languages like C++ and Ruby offer alternate methods (`at` and `fetch`, respectively) to opt-in to throwing an error on a bad access, while C# offers opt-in fallback value `TryGetValue` similar to Python's `get`.

Since JS, Java, Ruby, Go and Rust bake the fallback approach of `.get` into all hash lookups by default, it can't be that bad, one might think. It's true that this isn't the largest issue facing language designers and there are plenty of use cases for the no-throw access version, so it's unsurprising that there's no consensus across languages.

But as I've argued, Python (along with C#) has done better than these languages by making the assert option the default. It's a loss of safety and expressivity to opt-out of using it to report contract violations at the point of failure by indiscriminately using `.get` across the board.

Comment: something else:

```python
In [1]: from collections import defaultdict

In [2]: d = defaultdict(list)

In [3]: print(d.get('b'))
None

In [4]: print(d['b'])
[]
```

so, for `defaultdict` you need to be careful how you want to trigger the "globally default" value.

Comment: I disagree that using `try/catch` causes headaches, it can actually be very useful when paired with a solid error detection model. Slack notifications, emails, anything could be used instead of adding a silent `try/catch`.

Comment: @treckstar That's not what's being discussed here. We're talking about dict `.get()`, which suppresses the error and does not send you a Slack message or email. Sure, you can add an `if dct.get("missing key") is None: # report error` but that's also not what's being discussed. I'm talking about _indiscriminately suppressing errors_ with `.get()` to create an illusion of safety, while actually allowing `None`s to run loose in your code, unhandled. You were linked here from a thread where you advocated OP silence their invariant error, suppressing the problem rather than solving it.

Answer (score 5):

> Why dict.get(key) instead of dict[key]?

#### 0. Summary

Comparing to `dict[key]`, `dict.get` provides a fallback value when looking up for a key.

#### 1. Definition

get(key[, default])   [4. Built-in Types — Python 3.6.4rc1 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never raises a KeyError.

```
d = {"Name": "Harry", "Age": 17}
In [4]: d['gender']
KeyError: 'gender'
In [5]: d.get('gender', 'Not specified, please add it')
Out[5]: 'Not specified, please add it'
```

#### 2. Problem it solves.

If without `default value`, you have to write cumbersome codes to handle such an exception.

```
def get_harry_info(key):
    try:
        return "{}".format(d[key])
    except KeyError:
        return 'Not specified, please add it'
In [9]: get_harry_info('Name')
Out[9]: 'Harry'
In [10]: get_harry_info('Gender')
Out[10]: 'Not specified, please add it'
```

As a convenient solution, `dict.get` introduces an optional default value avoiding above unwiedly codes.

#### 3. Conclusion

`dict.get` has an additional default value option to deal with exception if key is absent from the dictionary

Answer (score 5):

One difference, that can be an advantage, is that if we are looking for a key that doesn't exist we will get None, not like when we use the brackets notation, in which case we will get an error thrown:

```
print(dictionary.get("address")) # None
print(dictionary["address"]) # throws KeyError: 'address'
```

Last thing that is cool about the get method, is that it receives an additional optional argument for a default value, that is if we tried to get the score value of a student, but the student doesn't have a score key we can get a 0 instead.

So instead of doing this (or something similar):

```
score = None
try:
    score = dictionary["score"]
except KeyError:
    score = 0
```

We can do this:

```
score = dictionary.get("score", 0)
# score = 0
```

Answer (score 5):

One other use-case that I do not see mentioned is as the `key` argument for functions like `sorted`, `max` and `min`. The `get` method allows for keys to be returned based on their values.

```
>>> ages = {"Harry": 17, "Lucy": 16, "Charlie": 18}
>>> print(sorted(ages, key=ages.get))
['Lucy', 'Harry', 'Charlie']
>>> print(max(ages, key=ages.get))
Charlie
>>> print(min(ages, key=ages.get))
Lucy
```

Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3282904/8716401) to a different question for providing this use-case!

Answer (score 3):

### Short answer

The square brackets are used for *conditional* lookups which can fail with a `KeyError` when the key is missing.

The `get()` method is used from *unconditional* lookups that never fail because a default value has been supplied.

### Base method and helper method

The square brackets call the `__getitem__` method which is fundamental for mappings like dicts.

The `get()` method is a helper layered on top of that functionality.  It is a short-cut for the common coding pattern:

```
try:
    v = d[k]
except KeyError:
    v = default_value
```

Answer (score 0):

With Python 3.8 and after, the dictionary `get()` method can be used with the walrus operator `:=` in an [assignment expression](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) to further reduce code:

```
if (name := dictonary.get("Name")) is not None
    return name
```

Using `[]` instead of `get()` would require wrapping the code in a try/except block and catching `KeyError` (not shown). And without the walrus operator, you would need another line of code:

```
name = dictionary.get("Name")
if (name is not None)
    return name
```

Comment: `if "Name" in dictionary: return dictionary["Name"]` is arguably clearer than the walrus operator version, with a small performance hit for two lookups, but with the added minor ability that it supports dicts that have None as a valid key rather than a placeholder for missing values. Actually, since `.get()` is a bit slower than `[]` last I checked, the performance hit may be my imagination just from eyeballing the code, so it's probably a non-issue either way.

Answer (score 0):

> For what purpose is this function useful?

Another use case where `get()` is useful is it induces a built-in function from a dictionary. As other answers mentioned, a default value can be specified for `dict.get`, which means the key itself can be returned if it's not in the dictionary, e.g. `my_dict.get(key, key)`. This means we can use `dict.get()` to replace values very succintly.

For example, from dictionary `dct = {1: 10}`, we can create the function `replacer = dct.get` (`type(mapper)` returns `builtin_function_or_method`). Then this function can be mapped to replace values.

```py
lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
new_list = list(map(replacer, lst, lst))   # [0, 10, 2, 3, 4]
```

It's, in fact, very fast to lookup values using the function induced by `dict.get()`. The following experiment shows that looking up via the function is over 2 times faster than looking up via the dictionary (it was done on Python 3.9.12).

```py
import timeit
setup = "lst = [0,1]*10000; dct = {1: 10}; replacer = dct.get"
t1 = min(timeit.repeat("list(map(replacer, lst, lst))", setup, number=100))
t2 = min(timeit.repeat("[dct[k] if k in dct else k for k in lst]", setup, number=100))

print(t2 / t1)   # 2.707056842200316
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition, dictionary.get function let's you specify default value if key does not exist while the other does not. You can return None if the key does not exists.The syntax is:

```
dictionary.get('key', default)
```

This becomes extremely handy when you want to database update column if they are given otherwise use existing value in one line.

```
 instance.first_name = validated_data.get('first_name', instance.first_name) 
 instance.last_name = validated_data.get('last_name', instance.last_name)
 instance.save()
```

Answer (score -1):

It allow you to provide a default value, instead of get an error when the value is not found. persuedocode like this :

```
class dictionary():
    def get(self,key,default):
         if self[key] is not found : 
               return default
         else:
               return self[key]
```

Comment: I understand this is pseudocode, but `if self[key] is not found :` would crash, so you might as well just write it as normal Python so it's less confusing.

Answer (score -1):

`.get()` gives you an "implicit" `try: ... except:`, making code cleaner and more robust when you get used to it.