# Default value for out-of-bounds list index

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a standard approach to getting an item from a list but returning a default value it is is out-of-bounds?

Just as an example I have a function like this now (well, many variants of this, my newest is for reading CSV files):

```
def list_get_def( lst, ndx, def_val ):
  if ndx >= len(lst):
    return def_val
  return lst[ndx]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `try-except` block and catch the `IndexError`.

```
>>> def testFunc(lst, index):
        try:
            return lst[index]
        except IndexError:
            return "abc"


>>> testFunc([1, 2, 3], 2)
3
>>> testFunc([1, 2, 3], 9)
'abc'
```

A similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125619/why-list-doesnt-have-safe-get-method-like-dictionary) discusses why lists don't have a `get` method like dictionaries do.

If you really do want to use the `if` statement, you can do it using just a single line of code.

```
>>> def testFunc(lst, index):
        return lst[index] if index < len(lst) else "abc"

>>> testFunc([1, 2, 3], 2)
3
>>> testFunc([1, 2, 3], 9)
'abc'
```

Comment: That would be longer than just checking the length.

Comment: Yes. But, it is the standard way of doing what you want.

Comment: Its also faster if your less likely to be out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want to overwrite the getimtem of lists you can write a get method like dict have:

```
class fancyList_if(list):
    def get(self, index, default = None):
        if (index > len(self)):
            return default
        return self.__getitem__(index)
```

if you rarely expect to get out of bounds then you can implement this as an exce

```
class fancyList_except(list):
    def get(self, index, default = None):
        try:
            self.__getitem__(index)
        except IndexError:
            return default
```

**benshmarks:**

```
In [58]: a = fancyList_if((1,3,4,5))

In [59]: b = fancyList_except((1,3,4,5))

In [60]: %timeit a.get(2, 10)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 494 ns per loop

In [61]: %timeit a.get(10, 10)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 305 ns per loop

In [62]: %timeit b.get(2, 10)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 409 ns per loop

In [63]: %timeit b.get(10, 10)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.67 us per loop
```

break even:

500hit + 300miss = 400hit + 1700miss

hit/miss = 14

so if you expect more than 1 in 14 look up 'fails' then use the if statement else use the try/catch.

Comment: I don't really want to alter the behaviour of an existing function, as that would cause confusion.