# getattr for a list index in Python?

Tags: python, getattr

I know I can do a try/except or if/else and set a default based on the error or else clause, but I was just wondering if there was a one liner that could do it like `getattr` can.

Comment: a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125619/why-list-doesnt-have-safe-get-method-like-dictionary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The good**: just `def` a helper function

```
def my_getitem(container, i, default=None):
    try:
        return container[i]
    except IndexError:
        return default
```

**The bad**: you can one-liner the conditional version

```
item = container[i] if i < len(container) else default
```

**The ugly**: these are hacks, don't use.

```
item = (container[i:] + [default])[0]

item, = container[i:i+1] or [default]

item = container[i] if container[i:] else default

item = dict(enumerate(container)).get(i, default)

item = next(iter(container[i:i+1]), default)
```

Comment: that's why it's bad :)

Comment: I actually kind of like the third hack, as long as you can assume `i` is non-negative.