# Python pandas extract values from dict within a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

Basically I would like to extract price value from this column, but the problem that if I use index [0] it would bring index[0] error in line 11 and price key also does not exit in this line.

```
ex
0    {u'availableToBack': [{u 'price' : 1.02, u 'size' : 2.15}], u 'availableToLay' : [], u 'tradedVolume' : []}
1    {u'availableToBack': [{u'price': 6.8, u'size':...
2    {u'availableToBack': [{u'price': 8.2, u'size':...
3    {u'availableToBack': [{u'price': 9.6, u'size':...
10   {u'availableToBack': [{u'price': 70.0, u'size'...
11   {u'availableToBack': [], u'availableToLay': []...
12   {u'availableToBack': [], u'availableToLay': []...
```

I use something like this

```
table['price'] = table['ex']['availableToBack'][0].apply(lambda x: x.get('price'))
```

Can you help me how to go around it, please?

JSON looks like this:

```
    u 'runners' : [{
            u 'status' : u 'ACTIVE',
            u 'handicap' : 0.0,
            u 'selectionId' : 10861647,
            u 'totalMatched' : 0.0,
            u 'adjustmentFactor' : 16.631,
            u 'ex' : {
                u 'availableToBack' : [{
                        u 'price' : 1.02,
                        u 'size' : 2.15
                    }
                ],
                u 'availableToLay' : [],
                u 'tradedVolume' : []
            }
        }, {
            u 'status' : u 'ACTIVE',
            u 'handicap' : 0.0,
            u 'selectionId' : 10861648,
            u 'totalMatched' : 0.0,
            u 'adjustmentFactor' : 13.237,
            u 'ex' : {
                u 'availableToBack' : [{
                        u 'price' : 1.01,
                        u 'size' : 7.11
                    }
                ],
                u 'availableToLay' : [],
                u 'tradedVolume' : []
            }
        },
```

Comment: can you post your json ? I don't see `:` after 0

Answer (score 0):

```
10   {u'availableToBack': [{u'price': 70.0, u'size'...
11   {u'availableToBack': [], u'availableToLay': []...
```

I just saw that your entry for availableToBack contains an empty list. Put in a test which will set it to [dict()] if the list value is empty. This will allow the `x.get('price', 0)` to work correctly. Then you will be able to process the value of 'price' as 0 in the rest of your code.

You will then not have to test for 'None'.

`x.get('price')` has no "default" value specified so it returns "None". Set up a default value (such as `x.get('price', 0)`) That way you should be able to perform the operations with a 0 price.

[Python dictionary get() Method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm)

> Description
>
> The method get() returns a value for the given key. If key is not
>   available then returns default value None. Syntax
>
> Following is the syntax for get() method −
>
> dict.get(key, default=None)
>
> Parameters
>
> ```
> key -- This is the Key to be searched in the dictionary.
>
> default -- This is the Value to be returned in case key does not exist.
> ```
>
> Return Value
>
> This method returns a value for the given key. If key is not available,
>   then it returns the default value None.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Python has a safe, built-in method for getting a value from a list without triggering an `IndexError`, but it is easy enough to write one. ([This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5125636/168594) has more detail on that.)

If I understand your intention correctly, this may help you. (Note that this only addresses the issue of getting the list item safely. You may want to use `.get` for each dictionary value you are retrieving for more safety.)

```
def safeget(seq, index, default=None):
    try:
        return seq[index]
    except IndexError:
        return default

for table in runners:
    price = safeget(table['ex']['availableToBack'], 0, default={}).get('price')
    print price
```

I tested against this structure, which has a an empty list for `u'availableToBack` in the second object.

```
runners = [
    {
        u'status' : u'ACTIVE',
        u'handicap' : 0.0,
        u'selectionId' : 10861647,
        u'totalMatched' : 0.0,
        u'adjustmentFactor' : 16.631,
        u'ex' : {
            u'availableToBack' : [
                    {u'price' : 1.02, u'size' : 2.15},
                ],
            u'availableToLay' : [],
            u'tradedVolume' : []
            }
    }, {
        u'status' : u'ACTIVE',
        u'handicap' : 0.0,
        u'selectionId' : 10861648,
        u'totalMatched' : 0.0,
        u'adjustmentFactor' : 13.237,
        u'ex' : {
            u'availableToBack' : [
                ## this one is MISSING a price
            ],
            u'availableToLay' : [],
            u'tradedVolume' : []
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: I think that he is using a dict() type with the key 'price' I think that the problem is that with no default, it returns a value of None.

Comment: I thought the issue was that his `availableToBack` is an array that may sometimes be empty, so his `[0]` index sometimes raised an IndexError. (Line 11 of his first example has an empty array.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary operator.  An empty list evaluates to false.

```
table['price'] = (table['ex']['availableToBack'][0].get('price') 
                  if table['ex']['availableToBack'] 
                  else None)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and decided to post it. Basically maybe I did not explain well, but the problem is inconsistencies of having anything within the list.

```
table['availableToBack.price'] = table['ex'].apply(lambda x: x['availableToBack'][0].get('price') if (len(x['availableToBack']) != 0) else None)
```

Comment: You can also do a list comprehension instead of apply/lambda.`[xx['availableToBack'][0].get('price') for xx in table['ex'] if len(xx['availableToBack']) else None]`