# javascript to python array translation

Tags: javascript, python, arrays

We are working on a project where we are translating javaScript code into python. Everything is going pretty smoothly, except for this one line of code that has given us errors on multiple translations:

> "primes" is an empty array BTW.

JavaScript:

```
 var primes = [];

 if(primes[primes.length - 1] > 3){...}
```

Python:

```
 primes = []

 if primes[len(primes) - 1] > 3:
      ......
```

This code works in javascript, however in Python we get an error. It seems as though we are trying to access an index of the list that doesn't exist.

This is the error:

> TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Does anyone have a workaround?

Comment: Please show the line where you declare `primes`.

Comment: `primes` is clearly *not* an empty array, it's `int`. Please create [mcve].

Comment: In both instances we are declaring an array, how are we supposed to declare it if we're declaring ints?

Comment: The code you've provided works fine when I copy it into my python 2.7 console... so the issue lies elsewhere. Follow the link from GingerPlusPlus and provide more information

Comment: The python code provided doesn't work fine, it produces an IndexError, because you can't access any index in an empty list.  The TypeError must be the result of some other portion of the code. So either the error message is not right, or the minimal example is not right.

Answer (score 4):

Python hasn't a safe get so you should change your code this way:

```
primes = []

if primes and primes[len(primes) - 1] > 3:
    ...
```

Even better, to get the last of the list you can use `primes[-1]`

```
primes = []

if primes and primes[-1] > 3:
    ...
```

Comment: To test that a list is not empty, you can simply use `if myList`, and to access the last element of a list you can use `myList[-1]`.

Comment: See also [Why list doesn't have safe “get” method like dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5125619/120999)