# Instance attributes in Python and __init__ method

Tags: python

I am trying to writing a program to read a configuration file but while testing it am having this error:

```
self.connection_attempts = self.config_file.get('CONNECTION_ATTEMPTS', 'TIME')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I ma pretty sure it is something I don't get, but it is few hours I am trying to understand where the problem is.
My `__init__` method looks like this:

```
import simpleconfigparser

class ReportGenerator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.config_parser = simpleconfigparser.configparser()
        self.config_file = config_parser.read('config.ini')
        self.connection_attempts = config_file.get('CONNECTION_ATTEMPTS', 'TIME')
        self.connection_timeout = config_file.get('CONNECTION_TIMEOUT', 'TIMEOUT')
        self.report_destination_path = config_file.get('REPORT', 'REPORT_PATH')
```

This code uses the [SimpleConfigParser](https://pypi.org/project/SimpleConfigParser/) package.

Comment: `config_file` is a `list` object, hence your error

Comment: Please refer to this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125619/why-doesnt-list-have-safe-get-method-like-dictionary

Comment: I noticed, but in another program I wrote i used axactly the same code, only outside the __init__ method, and it works

Comment: `config_parser.read(...)` creates a list. Lists in python cannot be inquired by `.get`. Maybe you can convert it into a `dictionary`

Comment: If `config_file` is a dictionary object this works with `get()`. The `config_file` might be a `list` object

Comment: @sanna: if you look carefully at the code where it works, you will notice that it is not the exact same code. in programming you have to be careful about little details, like the difference between `config_parser` and `config_file`.

Comment: Print the attribute, see how it looks like. It's a list. Depend on the contained objects you maybe can convert it into a dict.

Answer (score 2):

You want `config_parser.get()` not `config_file.get()`. `config_parser.read()` simply returns the list of config files successfully read after populating the config object. (Usually it is called `config` or `cfg`, not `config_parser`).

This list (`config_file`) serves no purpose in your code and you might as well not capture it at all.

```
from simpleconfigparser import simpleconfigparser

TIME = 5
TIMEOUT = 10
REPORT_PATH = '/tmp/'

class ReportGenerator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.config = simpleconfigparser()
        config.read('config.ini')

        self.connection_attempts = config.get('CONNECTION_ATTEMPTS', TIME)
        self.connection_timeout = config.get('CONNECTION_TIMEOUT', TIMEOUT)
        self.report_destination_path = config.get('REPORT', REPORT_PATH)
```

My guess would also be, that you use the default value in `.get()` the wrong way, but i cannot be certain with the information you have given.