# How to set values to a list if it is showing "list index out of range" in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, get

In python we have get() method  in dictionary to get values safely. Any way to achieve this in list?

```
my_dict = {'fruit':'apple','colour':'black'}
my_dict.get('colour','None') #returns black
my_dict.get('veg','None')  #returns None

my_list = ['apple','fish','blue','bottle','gold']
colour = my_list[2]
print(colour)  #returns blue
value = my_list[7] #gives error. Expected: need to return default value as None.
```

In my case length of my_list is not constant.Values are getting populated in runtime.If i try to get the index which is not present in the my_list it should return default value as None.
How to get the default values when list is not having requested index.?

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125619/why-doesnt-list-have-safe-get-method-like-dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Use `try-except` block -

```
try:
    value = my_list[7]
except:
    print("Value doesn't exist")
```

In case, the `try` statement has an error, it switches to the `except` block