# Get value at list/array index or "None" if out of range in Python

Tags: python

Is there clean way to get the value at a list index or `None` if the index is out or range in Python?

The obvious way to do it would be this:

```
if len(the_list) > i:
    return the_list[i]
else:
    return None
```

However, the verbosity reduces code readability. Is there a clean, simple, one-liner that can be used instead?

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. What about slices? Negative indexes? The ambiguity of a list with a None in it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the nth element of a python list or a default if not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492087/how-to-get-the-nth-element-of-a-python-list-or-a-default-if-not-available)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Try:

```
try:
    return the_list[i]
except IndexError:
    return None
```

Or, one liner:

```
l[i] if i < len(l) else None
```

Example:

```
>>> l=list(range(5))
>>> i=6
>>> print(l[i] if i < len(l) else None)
None
>>> i=2
>>> print(l[i] if i < len(l) else None)
2
```

Comment: This has the unfortunate side-effect of using exceptions as control flow, which his original already doesn't and this isn't much less verbose.

Comment: This is indeed much better to do, but it isn't exactly less verbose, is it?

Comment: @DanielDiPaolo: In python, using exceptions this way is encouraged and not frowned upon.

Comment: @BrtH: well theres two schools of thought on that the LBYL (Look before you leap (if statements)) crowd and the EAFP (easier to ask forgiveness then permission (try/excepts)) crowd... but yeah in general using exceptions this way is definitely not frowned upon ... but i think it largely comes down to personal preference

Comment: I doubt exception flow will be as performant as a simple if-else.

Comment: Except that in Python exception flow _is_ more performant: Exceptions are _very_ light in Python, and only incur their (limited) overhead when an exception occurs. An if statement means a comparison is ran when the code would have executed anyway. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522005/cost-of-exception-handlers-in-python) and [this doc](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#how-fast-are-exceptions)

Comment: Note that the second version doesn't work with negative indices

Comment: second version do not work if i=0, and every value under len(l)

Answer (score 50):

I find list slices good for this:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a = x [1:2]
>>> a
[2]
>>> b = x [4:5]
>>> b
[]
```

So, always access x[i:i+1], if you want x[i]. You'll get a list with the required element if it exists. Otherwise, you get an empty list.

Comment: Addendum: This can be expanded to be `my_list[idx: idx+1] or "Default_value"`. Readable and succinct! :)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as a one-liner that avoids an if and works with empty lists. It works well with lists created by list comprehension as well:
`a = [1,3,5,7,9];
b = [num for num in a if num % 2 == 0][0:1] or "No evens found";
print(b)
No evens found`

Comment: @Erich Nice but it results in a list, instead of a value. So full one liner will look ugly: `(my_list[idx: idx+1] or ["Default_value"])[0]`

Comment: @SergeyNudnov I agree with your solution. It's a bit hairy but the cleanest way to do it as a one-liner.  I would say that at this point it might warrant a small helper function in a personal lib

Comment: You can make this much shorter using unpacking assignment. Given the list splice `x[1:2]`, you could assign it to `var` via many forms of unpacking. Tuple unpacking: `(var,) = x[1:2]` or `var, = x[1:2]` or `var, *_ = x[1:2]`. List unpacking: `[var] = x[1:2]`. Whilst I normally don't use brackets for tuple unpacking, in this case I'd prefer `(var,) = x[1:2]` as it's both short and (IMHO) explicit, since the tuple form should be more recognisable.

Comment: @daveruinseverything If we are checking out of index, it would still give an error: `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 1, got 0)`.

Answer (score 16):

If you are dealing with small lists, you do not need to add an if statement or something of the sorts. An easy solution is to transform the list into a dict. Then you can use `dict.get`:

```
table = dict(enumerate(the_list))
return table.get(i)
```

You can even set another default value than `None`, using the second argument to `dict.get`. For example, use `table.get(i, 'unknown')` to return `'unknown'` if the index is out of range.

Note that this method does not work with negative indices.

Answer (score 11):

For your purposes you can exclude the `else` part as `None` is return by default if a given condition is not met.

```
def return_ele(x, i):
    if len(x) > i: return x[i]
```

Result

```
>>> x = [2,3,4]
>>> b = return_ele(x, 2)
>>> b
4
>>> b = return_ele(x, 5)
>>> b
>>> type(b)
<type 'NoneType'>
```

Answer (score 11):

Combining slicing and iterating

```
next(iter(the_list[i:i+1]), None)
```

Comment: Note to readers: The only way I can interpret this answer is that it is a joke. You should never use this as a solution to the problem in OP's question.

Comment: @MichaelGeary: I don't see why you think this is a joke. At the time of writing this is the only answer, which does not refer to the list twice, which is very handy when your list is a temporary object. Aside from that you are able choose the alternative return value all in one statement.

Comment: I like this because of it's one liner aspect but it seems it is actually the least performant. Check out @XerCis's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68112414/8285811) with benchmarks.

Answer (score 8):

```
return the_list[i] if len(the_list) > i else None
```

Comment: @JoranBeasley How in the world is a one liner more verbose than various multi-line statements?

Comment: @semicolon Another bad metric.

Answer (score 7):

**1. if...else...**

```py
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i, current in enumerate(l):
    following = l[i + 1] if i + 1 < len(l) else None
    print(current, following)
# 1 2
# 2 3
# 3 4
# 4 5
# 5 None
```

**2. try...except...**

```py
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i, current in enumerate(l):
    try:
        following = l[i + 1]
    except IndexError:
        following = None
    print(current, following)
# 1 2
# 2 3
# 3 4
# 4 5
# 5 None
```

**3. dict**

suitable for small list

```py
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
dl = dict(enumerate(l))
for i, current in enumerate(l):
    following = dl.get(i + 1)
    print(current, following)
# 1 2
# 2 3
# 3 4
# 4 5
# 5 None
```

**4. List slicing**

```py
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i, current in enumerate(l):
    following = next(iter(l[i + 1:i + 2]), None)
    print(current, following)
# 1 2
# 2 3
# 3 4
# 4 5
# 5 None
```

**5. itertools.zip_longest**

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i, (current, following) in enumerate(zip_longest(l, l[1:])):
    print(current, following)
# 1 2
# 2 3
# 3 4
# 4 5
# 5 None
```

Using Jupyter magic command of `%%timeit`

init

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

l = list(range(10000000))
```

Result

| Method | Consume |
| --- | --- |
| if...else... | 2.62 s |
| try...except... | 1.14 s |
| dict | 2.61 s |
| List slicing | 3.75 s |
| itertools.zip_longest | 1.14 s |

Comment: Thank you for presenting several scenarios + benchmarking them. A very insightful answer!

Answer (score 2):

Another one-liner:

```py
return((the_list + [None] * i)[i])
```

Comment: I LOVE this :) you only have to write `the_list` once..