# How to get a value of numpy ndarray at index or NaN for IndexError?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

My question is similar to this one

[Get value at list/array index or "None" if out of range in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186388/get-value-at-list-array-index-or-none-if-out-of-range-in-python)

but I want to use multidimensional numpy array.

Can this be done without checking the indexes beforehand?

```
data = np.ones((2,3,4))
idx1 = [0,1]
idx2 = [1,2]
idx3 = [0, 100]
data[idx1, idx2, idx3]
```

Desired output:

```
array([1., np.nan])
```

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem? If so, can you please mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given our data

```
import numpy as np    
data = np.ones((2,3,4))
idx = [[0,1], [1,2], [0, 100]]
shape = np.array(data.shape)
```

You can get any index column that extends past your original array using

```
invalids = np.any(idx > shape[:, None] - 1, axis=0)
```

and clip your indices to valid values using

```
valids = np.clip(idx, 0, shape[:, None] - 1)
```

these indicies can be used to index our array

```
out = data[valids.tolist()]
```

and the mask of invalid indices can be used to set outliers to `nan`

```
out[invalids] = np.nan
# array([ 1., nan])
```