# How to structure optional arguments in python

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to python and im wondering whats the best way is to stucture and build my code in a specific data validation case. I'm building cmd line script that takes 3 arguments and save them to variables. The third argument is optional. How should i handle the optional argument. I get promted for "IndexError: list index out of range" when im not specifing the third argument.

Whats the most simple and practical why to validate user input with a optional argument?

```
user_cat = sys.argv[1]
user_id = sys.argv[2]
user_guid = sys.argv[3]

def validate(user_cat, argv_cat_list, user_guid):
    if len(user_cat) > 10 or user_cat not in argv_cat_list:
        print("Error! Please specify a valid category (AddDevice, GetAccount, c, p, GetDevices, r ,s)")
        sys.exit()
    elif len(user_id) == 36 or user_id.startswith("SAM-") and len(user_guid) == False:
        getInfo()
        sys.exit()
    elif len(user_cat) >= 10 and len(user_guid) == 36 and user_id.startswith("FRA-"):
        print ("Test-hest!")
    else:
        print("Error! Please specify a valid input")
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

Comment: You might want to look at invoke (https://pypi.org/project/invoke/) if you're writing simple tasks, otherwise the standard library module argparse (https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) handles argument parsing for command line scripts.

Comment: ps:.. this `and len(user_guid) == False` is going to be true (`bool` is a subtype of `int`), but very confusing to read.

Comment: See [How to get the nth element of a python list or a default if not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492087/how-to-get-the-nth-element-of-a-python-list-or-a-default-if-not-available).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `argparse` for this. You don't *always* need flags, sometimes just a positional argument is better as it saves typing, compare e.g. with `cat`. Try the following example

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='LOLCATZ')
parser.add_argument('cat')
parser.add_argument('id')
parser.add_argument('guid')
parser.add_argument('optional1', nargs='?')  # positional and optional
parser.add_argument('--optional2')  # optional flag
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) library. Tutorial [here.](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html)

Write something like:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "[insert some description here]")
parser.add_argument('-i', "--user_cat", help = '[insert some help]')
parser.add_argument('-i', "--cat_list", help = '[insert more help]')
parser.add_argument('-u', "--user_guid", nargs = '?', help = '[insert some help]')
args = parser.parse_arg()
# Access the variables with args.user_cat, args.cat_list, etc.
```