# varible width for loop in python

Tags: python-3.x, loops, python-itertools

I'm not even sure if I'm describing this correctly, but I have a series of lists that I combine using `izip_longest`.

```
import  itertools

a = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
b = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']
c = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']


group = []
for i in (filter(None, g) for g in itertools.izip_longest(a, b, c)):
    group.append(i)
```

I follow that with a `for` loop

```
for idx, (x, y, z) in enumerate(group):
    print('Got ' + x + ', ' + y + ', ' + z)
```

However, sometimes I have a situation where one or more of the lists going into `izip_longest` are empty

For example

```
a = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
b = []
c = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']
```

This causes a problem in the `for` loop.  How can I specify a variable number of "output arguments" (not sure this is the right term) from the for loop ...

e.g. if list `b` is empty make the for loop be something like

```
for idx, (x,z) in enumerate(group):
   ...
```

Comment: there will always be one ... could I do something like `((x,*_))`?  but how are those additional variables referred to in the body of the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Really, you should only use the unpacking syntax (`(x, y, z)`) if you know exactly how large the collection is. There's workarounds like using a "rest operator" to grab extras:

```
(a, b, *z) = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

>>> z
[3, 4, 5]
```

but that's ugly, and there isn't a great way to grab less than a certain amount that I know of.

If the size of a collection can vary, I'd just treat it as a list, and check/extract data from it as needed. In your particular example, this can be done easily with `join`:

```
for idx, members in enumerate(group):
    print('Got ' + ', '.join(members))
```

Of course, in more complicated scenarios, you may want to refer to individual elements. In that case, using some way of [getting an element with a default](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2492087/3000206) would work, or just use an `if` to check from the beginning

I think trying to force unpacking here is complicating things; although, I'd love to be proven wrong.

Comment: I'll give this a try ... the problem is that I'll need to access each in member (a variable number) using a method that only allows one input variable ... so I think I need to embed another loop.

Comment: @agf1997 I'd need to see a minimal example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes, sorry ... obviously the questions scope is a little bigger than I initially anticipated.  Let me see what I can work up.